# Entity Framework Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework

Estou tentando executar o seguinte código, porém esta dando erro onde está tentando inserir novamente o Estado no meu banco, porém ele foi buscado através de outra conexão

sei que uma solução seria setar direto o EstadoId, porém gostaria de usar o Navigation só para relacionar os registro, ou seja, não quero a o Estado seja salvo junto com a cidade.
O que poderia fazer para resolver esta questão?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Estado estado = GetEstado();

        using(TesteContext context = new TesteContext())
        {
            Cidade cidade = new Cidade();                
            cidade.Estado = estado;
            cidade.Descricao = "SM";
            context.Cidade.Add(cidade);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    static Estado GetEstado()
    {
        using (TesteContext context = new TesteContext())
        {
            var estado = context.Estado.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EstadoId == 43);

            if (estado == null)
            {
                estado = new Estado();
                estado.EstadoId = 43;
                estado.Descricao = "RS";
                context.Estado.Add(estado);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return estado;
        }
    }

    public class TesteContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Estado> Estado { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Cidade> Cidade { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TesteContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TesteContext>());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class Estado
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cidade
    {
        [Key]            
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CidadeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EstadoId")]
        public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faça isso:

```
if (estado == null)
{
    estado = new Estado();
    estado.EstadoId = 43; // <--- Evite isso
    estado.Descricao = "RS";
    context.Estado.Add(estado);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

A definição da chave primária deve ser feita pelo Entity Framework, e não por você. O correto é a pesquisa ser da seguinte forma para o seu exemplo:

```
var estado = context.Estado.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Descricao == "RS");
```

Tenho certeza de que o código não vai ficar assim no final. É apenas um teste.

Outra coisa é a respeito de como você utiliza os contextos para carregar as informações. Fazendo isso:

```
using (TesteContext context = new TesteContext())
{ ... }
```

Você está eliminando o contexto que carrega sua informação ao retornar o objeto. Sem um contexto ativo, o objeto não é observado pelo Entity Framework e considerado um novo objeto.

O *Controller* já possui em seu `Dispose` a capacidade de eliminar o contexto ao fim do ciclo de execução. Portanto, a construção `using` não precisa ser usada.

Ao invés disso, declare o contexto fora dos seus métodos. Como não é um *Controller* o seu caso, passe o mesmo contexto utilizado para inserir a *Cidade* também para a pesquisa e a inserção do *Estado*:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new TesteContext();

    var estado = GetEstado(context);

    var cidade = new Cidade();                
    cidade.Estado = estado;
    cidade.Descricao = "SM";
    context.Cidade.Add(cidade);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

static Estado GetEstado(TesteContext context)
{
    var estado = context.Estado.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Descricao == "RS");

    if (estado == null)
    {
        estado = new Estado();
        // estado.EstadoId = 43;
        estado.Descricao = "RS";
        context.Estado.Add(estado);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return estado;
}
```

Comment: A dificuldade dos programadores é entender que o uso da seleção por Id não deve ser feito de maneira humana. O Id é um identificador único, interno, de cada registro de cada entidade do sistema.

Comment: Eu uso o estado.EstadoId = 43 pelo fato de ser o código IBGE do estado e já estar relacionado o com a cidade, facilita futuramente quando precisar do código do ibge do estado na cidade, se for deixar por conta do EF o Id, teria que ter uma Coluna CodigoIbge.
o complicado é que hoje eu não compartilho meu contexto com minhas classes, o que admito ser um erro que terei que corrigir, cada classes instancia seu contexto, por isso que separei o GetEstado em um outro método com um outro contexto.